# "Failed to enable unit" error enabling vncserver on RHEL 9

Tags: systemd, rhel, vnc, tigervnc

I have installed Tiger VNC Server on RHEL 9, but when I try to enable the service I get the following error:

```
# systemctl enable vncserver@.service
Failed to enable unit: File multi-user.target: Identifier removed
```

I am running in multi-user mode:

```
root# systemctl get-default
multi-user.target
```

I have not made any edits to the default vncserver@.service file.

What would cause the above error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run the service with user-bus. In your vncserver systemd service file, change the `multi-user.target` to `default.target`. After that, do `systemctl daemon-reload` and try enabling your service again